# UINavigationBar with Search icon - push modal search view when clicked

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am creating a Navigation-Based application. The nav bar has a search icon; when it is clicked I push a SearchViewController onto the navigation controller (containing a search bar and tableview).

I am hiding the table view when the search view loads in an attempt to have the previous view (the view from which the search icon was selected) show behind the search view, but it appears that the navigation controller is removing this view. If I add the search view as a subview on the appDelegates's window I can see the previous view behind the search view, but the app crashes when I click in the search bar (it doesn't appear to give control to the view controller attached to the search view).

I am looking for any suggestions on how to achieve my desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you give up on this? I'm suprised there's no answer and no comments.

Answer (score 0):

it sure is late as a response... but uinavigationbar's push view...
pushes a new view controller, removing the old one from the active window...

if you want to have a search controller behave like that, you should use a UISearchBarController and set it's search bar as header of your original table view..

the searchbar controller will show and hide the search result table view, if you want the old table to be shown, you should change the table on the search bar, so it's transparent first.

Pushing a new view is not a solution because you totally change the old view (remove it from the window)

greetings